# CSS3: Add vertical spacing between lines

Tags: jquery-ui, css

I have some jQuery UI buttons that look like this:

[image]

How can I add vertical spacing between the rows? Modifying the CSS properties `margin-top` and `padding-top` didn't work.

Here is the HTML that exemplifies a single button:

```
<div>
    <input type="checkbox" class="tool_toggle" id="tool_#" checked /><label for="tool_#">... tool name...</label>
    ... more inputs ...
</div>
```

This HTML input tag is simply repeated 11 times. The buttons wrap around as they should in the div container.

Comment: Without seeing your HTML, it's impossible to say.

Comment: If they are `inline`, have you tried `margin-left/right`?

Comment: Post your CSS as well.

Comment: There is no CSS currently associated with the buttons.

Comment: How about `line-height`?

Comment: @DylanKlomparens It's just jQuery UI CSS?

Comment: @Jaa-c Didn't seem to have any effect.

Comment: @JoshC Yes, just jQuery UI CSS.

Comment: Then it is something in jQuery UI causing this. How do the properties of the elements look like when you inspect them in Developer Tools in your browser.

Comment: Ah ha, @Jaa-c, setting line-spacing to a higher value (500%) worked great! That is for the div that the buttons are enclosed in. Thanks! Post and answer and I'll select it complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by setting `line-height` to the element that contains the buttons.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify that the buttons are `display:inline-block` before you can add `margin-top` or `padding-top`. This is because inline elements can not have top or bottom margins or padding.

You didnt post enough code to tell for certain so this is a guess. Post your CSS or make a http://jsfiddle.net/ if you want a proper answer